# Width of rotated text

Tags: html, css

I've got a table where I'm rotating the `th`
This is the code

```css
table.results-table span {
  display:block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-weight:300;
}
```

```html
<table class="results-table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works fine, however the `th` is the width as if the text wasn't rotated which causes it to break on smaller screens. Is there any way to set the width so it's only as wide as the rotated text?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the wanted output could be to use the `writing-mode` property :

```
table.results-table span {
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```css
table.results-table span {
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<table class="results-table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply `rotate` transform to `<th>` instead of `<span>`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
table.results-table th {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-weight:300;
}
th,td{padding:10px;text-align:center;}
body{font:13px Verdana;}
```

```html
<table class="results-table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
    <th><span>Test1</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Employee 1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `<td>`'s and `<th>`'s are still the width of the `<th>` before rotation.